# Self sorting array's sort function in C++ custom class

Tags: c++, sorting, variable-assignment

so I'm trying to make an array class that lets you add a number, and the add function will place that number into an array in a position with the following criteria: the array's rows AND columns must be in ascending numerical order.  So

1 2
3 4

is fine, whereas

1 3
4 2

fails, as 4 > 2 and 3 > 2 but

1 3
2 4

is acceptable

the assignment is vague, it doesn't really matter whether it makes the array like the first one, or the third one, as long as the constraints are met.  I've made my add function by simply writing out a list of cases and trying to attend to each one.  When the array is initialized, it puts INTEGER_MAX in each of the spots for placeholding and evaluative purposes.  I'm not sure if it's the order of evaluation or what, but sometimes it places a number that I add under an INTEGER_MAX or otherwise out of order. I've been working on this a while, and am hesitant to ask for help, but I thought it might be easier with a fresh pair of eyes. I'm going to add the code for the function, and the class, I don't know if/how I should include the dependant classes to allow for others to compile the code?  I'm new to SO and a bit sick so just bear with me and I'll provide whatever information is needed to help.  Thank you!

Here's the add() function itself:

```
void add(int i) {

    //THIS NEEDS TO BE FIXED ITS GOING TO THE WRONG PLACES

    if (matrix[row - 1][col - 1] != INT_MAX){ //if the last element in the VNT is full 
        cout<<"VNT is full!"<<endl; 
    }
    else {
        matrix[row - 1][col - 1] = i;
        //cout << "matrix["<<row-1<<"]["<<col-1<<"] = " <<matrix[row - 1][col - 1]<<endl;
        int r = row - 1;
        int c = col - 1;
        while (true) {
            if (r == 0 && c == 0) //no neighbor left, no neighbor above, correct position
                break;
            else if (c == 0) { //no neighbor left
                if (matrix[c][r-1] > i) { //if above is larger, swap
                    swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                    r--; //decrement row to go through stability check again
                }
                else        //above is smaller, break
                    break;
            }
            else if (r == 0) { //no neighbor above
                if (matrix[c-1][r] > i) { //if left is larger, swap
                    swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                    c--; //decrement column to go through stability check again
                }
                else        //left is smaller, break
                    break;
            }

            else if (matrix[r][c-1] < i && matrix[r-1][c] < i) //left and above are both smaller, right position
                break;

            else if (matrix[r][c-1] > i && matrix[r-1][c] > i) { //both left and above are potential candidates for switch
                if (matrix[r][c-1] >= matrix[c][r-1]) { //if left candidate is larger than top candidate, swap with that to preserve column
                    swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                    cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r<<"]["<<c-1<<"]"<<endl;
                    c--; //decrement column to go through stability check again
                }
                else { //otherwise swap with neighbor above
                    swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                    cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r-1<<"]["<<c<<"]"<<endl;
                    r--; //decrement row to go through stability check again
                }
            }
            else if (matrix[r][c-1] > i) { //only left neighbor is larger, swap left
                swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r<<"]["<<c-1<<"]"<<endl;
                r--;
            }
            else if (matrix[r-1][c] > i) { //only the above neighbor is larger, switch with that
                swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r-1<<"]["<<c<<"]"<<endl;
                c--;
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

and then here is the larger class file for context (please let me know if there's more needed) :

```
    #include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#define main poop
#include "SA.cpp"
#include "safeMatrix.cpp"
using namespace std;
#undef main

//friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, VNT v);

class VNT {

private:
    SafeMatrix <int> matrix;
    int row;
    int col;

public:

    VNT (int r, int c) : matrix (r, c) {  //2 param constructor
        //cout << "r = " << r << " c = " << c << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                //cout << "i = " << i << " j = " << j;
                matrix[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        row = r; //initialize the rows and cols vars to hold the SIZE of the array !POSSIBLE OFF BY 1 ERRORS!
        col = c;
    }

    ~VNT() { //destructor
        cout << "VNT Destructor called\n";
    }

    void add(int i) {

        //THIS NEEDS TO BE FIXED ITS GOING TO THE WRONG PLACES

        if (matrix[row - 1][col - 1] != INT_MAX){ //if the last element in the VNT is full 
            cout<<"VNT is full!"<<endl; 
        }
        else {
            matrix[row - 1][col - 1] = i;
            //cout << "matrix["<<row-1<<"]["<<col-1<<"] = " <<matrix[row - 1][col - 1]<<endl;
            int r = row - 1;
            int c = col - 1;
            while (true) {
                if (r == 0 && c == 0) //no neighbor left, no neighbor above, correct position
                    break;
                else if (c == 0) { //no neighbor left
                    if (matrix[c][r-1] > i) { //if above is larger, swap
                        swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                        r--; //decrement row to go through stability check again
                    }
                    else        //above is smaller, break
                        break;
                }
                else if (r == 0) { //no neighbor above
                    if (matrix[c-1][r] > i) { //if left is larger, swap
                        swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                        c--; //decrement column to go through stability check again
                    }
                    else        //left is smaller, break
                        break;
                }

                else if (matrix[r][c-1] < i && matrix[r-1][c] < i) //left and above are both smaller, right position
                    break;

                else if (matrix[r][c-1] > i && matrix[r-1][c] > i) { //both left and above are potential candidates for switch
                    if (matrix[r][c-1] >= matrix[c][r-1]) { //if left candidate is larger than top candidate, swap with that to preserve column
                        swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                        cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r<<"]["<<c-1<<"]"<<endl;
                        c--; //decrement column to go through stability check again
                    }
                    else { //otherwise swap with neighbor above
                        swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                        cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r-1<<"]["<<c<<"]"<<endl;
                        r--; //decrement row to go through stability check again
                    }
                }
                else if (matrix[r][c-1] > i) { //only left neighbor is larger, swap left
                    swap (r, c, r, c-1);
                    cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r<<"]["<<c-1<<"]"<<endl;
                    r--;
                }
                else if (matrix[r-1][c] > i) { //only the above neighbor is larger, switch with that
                    swap (r, c, r-1, c);
                    cout << "Swapping a["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] with a["<<r-1<<"]["<<c<<"]"<<endl;
                    c--;
                }

            } 
        }
    }

    int getMin() { //removes the first element and then resort the matrix
        int value;
        if (matrix[0][0] == INT_MAX){ // if the VNT is empty  it will output this message but 
            cout<<"VNT is empty"<<endl;
            return -1; 
        }
        else { 
            value = matrix[0][0]; // value to be returned 
            matrix[0][0] = INT_MAX; // set the first element to INT_MAX 
            int r = 0;
            int c = 0;
            while (r < row || c < col) {
                if (matrix[r][c] > matrix[r+1][c] && matrix[r][c] > matrix[r][c+1]) { //if both the element to the right and below are candidates
                    if (matrix[r][c+1] < matrix[r+1][c]) { //if swapping with left wont invalidate the column, do that
                        swap(r, c, r, c+1);
                        c++;
                    }
                    else { //otherwise swap with bottom
                        swap(r, c, r+1, c);
                        r++;
                    }           
                }
                else if (matrix[r][c] > matrix[r][c+1]) {
                    swap(r, c, r, c+1);
                    c++;
                }
                else if (matrix[r][c] > matrix[r+1][c]) {
                    swap(r, c, r+1, c);
                    r++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return value; //scope?!?        
    }

    void sort(int k[], int size) {
        if (size > row*col)
            cout << "Too many elements for the VNT"<< endl;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){ 
                for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){ 
                    matrix[i][j] = INT_MAX; //set every element in the VNT to INT_MAX 
                }
            }  
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
                add(k[i]); // will use the member function to add each element to the VNT 
            }
        }   
    }

    void swap (int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
        int temp = matrix[r1][c1];
        matrix[r1][c1] = matrix[r2][c2];
        matrix [r2][c2] = temp;
    }

    bool find (int i) {
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                if (matrix[r][c] == i)
                    return true;
                // else if (matrix[r][c] > i)
                    // return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, VNT v);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, VNT v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < v.col; j++) {
                if (v.matrix[i][j] == INT_MAX)
                    os << "*" << " ";
                else 
                    os << v.matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            os << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }

int main(){
    VNT a(5,5);
    cout << a;
    VNT b(3,3);
    cout << b;
    b.add(1);   
    b.add(5);
    //cout << a.getMin();
    //a.add(1);
    //cout << b;
    //b.add(10);
    cout << b;
    b.add(2);
    b.add(3);
    cout << b;

    b.add(10);
    b.add(7);
    b.add(11);
    cout << b;
    cout << b.find(1)<<endl;
    VNT m(3,5);
    cout << m;
    //cout << c;

};
```

right now, for me, the output of the code for matrix b is:

1 3 *
2 7 11
5 10 *

(* stands for INTEGER_MAX)

Hope I formatted it right, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to work with the array as if it were a single dimension, and keep the whole thing sorted.

Then when you display it, you can print it out either column-wise or row-wise, and it's guaranteed to meet your constraints. Of the two, printing it out row-wise will almost certainly be (quite a bit) easier.

```
std::vector<int> data;

void insert(int d) { 
    auto pos = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), d);
    data.insert(pos, d);
}

void print(int columns) { 
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
       if (i % columns == 0)
           std::cout << "\n";
       std::cout << data[i];
    }
}
```

Quick test driver program:

```
int main(){
    insert(4);
    insert(2);
    print(2);
    std::cout << "\n";
    insert(3);
    insert(1);
    print(2);
}
```

Results:

```
24

12
34
```

Of course, for any real use, you undoubtedly do *not* want to make the data a global, nor have functions like `insert` or `print` that implicitly operate on that global, but the I hope the basic idea comes through nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I wasn't even thinking of it like that but that's much, much more approachable than the myriad of cases I was trying to swap it into.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet I've written below.

I agree with Jerry, that its easier to just use and sort a one-dimensional array and just project it into the form you need. I used the same sort routine as Jerry except that this will lay out your numbers on a square matrix of your desired width.

```
#define DIMENSION_SIZE 10

int matrix[DIMENSION_SIZE+1][DIMENSION_SIZE+1];

std::vector<int> data;

void insert(int d) { 
    auto pos = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), d);
    data.insert(pos, d);
}

int main()
{
    for (int ctr=0;ctr<DIMENSION_SIZE*DIMENSION_SIZE;++ctr) {
        insert(rand());
    }

    int level = 0;
    int levelsub = 0;

    for (int ctr=0;ctr<DIMENSION_SIZE*DIMENSION_SIZE;++ctr) {
        matrix[level-levelsub][levelsub] = data.at(ctr);

        if (++levelsub >  (level >= DIMENSION_SIZE ? DIMENSION_SIZE -1 : level)) {
            ++level;
            levelsub= 0;
            if (level >= DIMENSION_SIZE) {
                levelsub+=level - DIMENSION_SIZE+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int ctr_y=0;ctr_y<DIMENSION_SIZE;++ctr_y) { 
        for (int ctr_x=0;ctr_x<DIMENSION_SIZE;++ctr_x) {
            std::cout << matrix[ctr_x][ctr_y] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output on my machine:

```
41      153     292     1842    3035    4966    6729    9741    12316   15350

288     491     1869    3548    5436    6868    9894    12382   15724   18467

778     2082    3902    5447    7376    9961    12623   15890   18716   19954

2995    4664    5537    7711    11323   12859   16118   18756   20037   23805

4827    5705    8723    11478   13931   16541   19169   21538   23811   25547

6334    8942    11538   14604   16827   19264   21726   24084   25667   27446

9040    11840   14771   16944   19629   22190   24370   26299   27529   28703

11942   15006   17035   19718   22648   24393   26308   27644   29358   31101

15141   17421   19895   22929   24464   26500   28145   30106   31322   32439

17673   19912   23281   24626   26962   28253   30333   32391   32662   32757
```

The output should always be sorted horizontally and verticall (even diagonally!)